# Model speedup using weights in R

Tags: r, cox-model, lm

I need to run a cox-regression on a huge data set (millions) with only a few unique rows (hundreds) and regressing on categorical variable `group`. I could use just `Surv(t, c) ~ group`, but this would take a very long time. I was thinking about including only unique rows together with their count as a `weights` argument.

How would you do this for this specific example? Is it possible to do such a function for generic formula?